# App Isn't Showing After Being Moved To System/Priv-App

Tags: android

I've made a test app with " Hello world " example, Simple enough, And I've moved it to System/App at first and set the permissions, After rebooting the app was gone, Tried to move it to Priv-app, Reboot the same thing .

Changed the Version to a newer one, Moved, It showed up!

Made some changes, Replaced the Apk, now showing up, Updated the version, Showed up.

This is really weird, didn't happen to me before, Here's the log :

```
02-04 04:26:09.208 1185-1185/? W/PackageManager: Package com.abohani.test at /system/priv-app/test reverting from /data/app/com.test.test-1: new version 3 better than installed 2
02-04 04:26:09.226 1185-1185/? W/PackageManager: Trying to update system app code path from /data/app/com.abohani.test-1 to /system/priv-app/test
```

As it's Lollipop, I've put it in a folder with the same name, test/test.apk .

Comment: To be noted, there is no match with the following : /data/app/com.abohani.test-1 .